Unit Test Repository without mocking in Flutter/Dart
How to UNIT Test the Repository in flutter/dart without mocking ?
Need to test real data from end point..
Also, why do we need to use mockito ?
class Repository 
    {
      final dio = Dio();
      final NetworkManager networkManager;
      Repository({required this.networkManager});
      Future<TodoModel> getTodo() async {
        if (networkManager.isNetworkAvailable())
        {
          final response = await dio.get('https://dummyjson.com/todos');
          return response.data['todos'].map<TodoModel>((item) {
           return TodoModel.fromJson(item);
          }).toList();
        } 
        else 
        {
          return const TodoModel(id: 999, todo: "FailedTODO", completed: false, userId: 10101);
        }
      }
    }
    
    class NetworkManager 
    {
      bool isNetworkAvailable() 
      {
        return true;
      }
    }


Just an aside: Mocktail is the modern replacement for mockito.

As another side note, making actual HTTP requests kinda defeats the purpose of unit testing altogether. The idea is to actually test the logic you're building and not an integration. A unit test should be fast and easily repeatable. In your case, if you were to test the actual response provided by the service, you'd be doing an integration test and this would be a bit slower than the unit test, could incur extra costs and depends on an internet connection and that the service is available. You should instead mock the response data and test that the logic is correct.

You can try this, testWidgets like this: Url
This is easy way for testing logic inside project flutter.
